# What is the time complexity of the following search algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, time-complexity, binary-search

```
/* 
 * V is sorted 
 * V.size() = N
 * The function is initially called as searchNumOccurrence(V, k, 0, N-1)
 */

int searchNumOccurrence(vector<int> &V, int k, int start, int end) {
    if (start > end) return 0;
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (V[mid] < k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
    if (V[mid] > k) return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1);
    return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1) + 1 + searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
}
```

What is the time complexity of this code snippet? I feel like its O(logN) but the correct answer is O(N). Can someone explain clearly why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `O(N)` because if you always take this "branch" (the array contains `N` elements with value `k`)

```
return searchNumOccurrence(V, k, start, mid - 1) + 1 + searchNumOccurrence(V, k, mid + 1, end);
```

you have to do 2 calls, and you can image it like a complete tree traversal, which is `O(N)`

Comment: ok but what about the two searchNumOccurence that execute before this last statement. Won't we consider those? And in the last statement too; in both the calls the time complexity should be log(N). Can you elaborate?

Comment: for eg. in the last statement; its not complete transversal. Its log(N) (binary search) two times both ofcourse ultimately returning 0. i.e 2*log(N)

Comment: @DivijJain The worst case is when `V` contains nothing but N copies of `k` (i.e., all elements are identical).  Then you execute that last return statement N times. The best case (when `V` has 0 or 1 elements with `k`) is O(log(N)) and that last return statement will not be executed.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm ah ok got it. Thanks. So basically those 2 statements in the middle won't ever be executed in the worst-case scenario.

Comment: @DivijJain exactly, those 2 branches are lighter then the third one, and since O(f(n)) is a upper limit, you need to find a function which is always greater/equal to your program asymptotically